# Filter for Elasticksearch Nest

Tags: .net, elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

So, i'm working to implementing filter into SearchDescriptor for Elasticsearch.
I using Nest. I have filter with structure like  Filters: { sex:{}, status:{}}

in code it's looks like

```
public class Filter 
{
   public List<string> Sex {get;set;}
   public List<string> Status {get;set;}
}
```

this values i get from request query.

and i have Search descriptor

```
var query = descriptor
            .From(skip)
            .Take(take)
            .Query(q => q.QueryString(s => s.Query(queryString)
                .Fields(searchFields.Select(x => new Field(x)).ToArray())))
            .Query(q => q.Terms(c => c
                .Boost(1.1)
                .Field(p => p.Status)
                .Terms(filter.Status)))
            .Highlight(h => h
                .Fields(searchFields
                    .Select<>, IHighlightField>>(sf =>
                        hfd => hfd.Field(sf)).ToArray()));
```

also i have projection class to elasticsearch model with properties like

```
public string Sex {get;set;}
public string Status {get;set}
```

my question is how can i add filters by my field into search descriptor?

Comment: can you explain what you mean by  "how can i add filters by my field into search descriptor"

Comment: @jaspreetchahal i mean how can i search (filter) by array values